# iOS PRODUCT_NAME not the display and wrapper name

Tags: ios, xcode

For my iOS app I am trying to have multiple build configurations so I can create development and production builds that target different servers, configurations etc.

In Xcode I have created another build configuration and scheme to target this configuration. So I have the separate configuration/schemes as:

*Dev version*

`PRODUCT_NAME=MyApp-dev
BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=com.organisation.myapp-dev`

*Original Version*

`PRODUCT_NAME=MyApp
BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=com.organisation.myapp`

Both configurations can be built with the different schemes. Both will run on the same device because of the different identifier, but the dev version still shows MyApp on the home screen. When looking in the build products, it produces a MyApp.app bundle with a target inside it of MyApp-dev.

Is there another setting to change the wrapper name from MyApp.app to MyApp-dev.app? And any other setting that may be preventing PRODUCT_NAME setting to be used in the app display name?

edit: In the info.plist file, both the `CFBundleName` and `CFBundleDisplayName` are set to `$(PRODUCT_NAME)`

n.b. I have done this before with another app and all is working fine there, hence the query if another developer has changed a more targeted setting that overrides this change.

Comment: Why do you need different product names/bundle ids in order to target different servers etc?  What's wrong with a compiler constant, setup with `-D`?

Comment: So they can run side-by-side on the same device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a InfoPlist.strings file in the project that was overriding CFBundleDisplayName. I removed this definition from this file and all worked as desired.

The project is not localised and so I never considered this override! Hopefully if someone else comes across this, remember settings in Info.plist can be overriden with localised strings in this file.